# Extract an integer value from a string that is in a list that is in a dataframe column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I have a dataframe that contains a column "Tickets" that now contains a single integer value as a string inside of a series.

```
print(type(train_tickets.Ticket))

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series>
```

```
train_tickets["Ticket"].head()

# Returns
1    [211536]
2    [112053]
3      [6607]
4    [111369]
5    [370376]
```

What I want:

```
1    211536
2    112053
3      6607
4    111369
5    370376
```

I can convert the individual numbers using this, but I haven't been able to get a loop or lambda function to return what I'm expecting.

```
int(train_tickets["Ticket"][0][0])

# returns 
21171
```

I have tried this loop (and associated lambda format)

```
for row in train_tickets["Ticket"]:
    Y = int(train_tickets["Ticket"][row][0])
```

but it's returning a Key Error,  self._get_with(key)
How can I do this with .apply(lambda ) or a loop of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
train_tickets.Ticket = train_tickets.Ticket.str[0]
```

---

If values inside the list are of type string you can do:

```py
train_tickets.Ticket = train_tickets.Ticket.str[0].astype(int)
```

To convert them to integer.